# Allocate memory in a C++ dll, free in C#

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management

I am new in C# and trying to communicate C# with C++ dll. My main purpose is allocating memory in C# using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()`, assign values in it and pass the reference of `IntPtr` to C++ dll. On the side of C++ dll, I'm changing the allocated memory size with `malloc()`, assign variables. In the end, I print values in C#. Until this point, everything works fine.

But when I try to free allocated memory in C# with `Marshal.FreeHGlobal()`, I get an error.

Actually, I search a lot to how I should implement my code with these functions. I found a solution that says I must write a function in the DLL for deallocating the memory and call this function. But my manager told me, I need to do this work in C# side. So I can't use that solution. Also, I found some other ideas which use COM but the manager doesn't want to use COM. So I can't use COM. Here some codes;

Allocating the memory in C#

```cs
var offset = 0;
var size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(dVehicle)) * denemeVehicle.Count();
IntPtr vehPnt;
vehPnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

for(var i = 0; i < denemeVehicle.Count(); i++)
{
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(denemeVehicle[i], new IntPtr(vehPnt.ToInt64() + offset), false);
    offset += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(dVehicle));
}
```

Changing the allocated memory size in C++

```cpp
*vehicles = (dVehicle*) malloc(sizeof(dVehicle) * (new_VehSize));
```

Free the allocated memory

```cs
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(vehPnt); // The error shows up in here
```

And this is error message;

> The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))

Comment: How could `FreeHGlobal` know that `vehPnt` might be allocated by `malloc` or `AllocHGlobal`. `AllocHGlobal` uses ` LocalAlloc` internally which is very different from `malloc`. Tell your manager that there's no way to free that memory from the C# side if it doesn't know how it is allocated

Comment: The *safe* practice is that the code that allocates, owns the memory. And ass `Neijwiert` you don't know what `malloc` did to allocate the memory. It *is* possible and actually quite common to customize allocation strategies. In fact, if you use `malloc` in C++ you have a major bug already. You should be using `new` at least and vectors instead of pointers

Comment: Unless you allocate `vehicles` with `LocalAlloc` and with flag `LMEM_FIXED` or use `AllocCoTaskMem` and allocate with `CoTaskMemAlloc` on the c++ side there's no way you can use `FreeHGlobal` or `FreeCoTaskMem`

Comment: Visual C++ has several classes that make interoperability with .NET easier. If you intend to use your C++ library with .NET, you should probably use them instead of using pointer arithmetic and raw memory allocations

Comment: I suggest reading Stroustrup's [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#S-resource) especially [Avoid malloc and free](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-mallocfree), [Avoid calling new and delete explicitly](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly) and the [C-Style programming](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#S-cpl) section.

Comment: The article [Marshaling .NET and STL Collections in C++/CLI](https://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2014/08/25/marshaling-net-stl-collections-ccli/) shows how to move STL containers from C++ to .NET and back

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response. As I understand, I can't use malloc() for my purpose. What should I use instead of malloc()? Any succession?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Marshal.FreeHGlobal()` cannot free memory that was allocated with the C `malloc()` function. The memory must be "from the global heap allocated by [Marshal.]AllocHGlobal, [Marshal.]ReAllocHGlobal, **or any equivalent unmanaged API method**."

Internally, `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` and `Marshal.FreeHGlobal()` use the Win32 `LocalAlloc()` and `LocalFree()` functions. This is documented on MSDN.

Otherwise, if you want the DLL to allocate the memory however it wants, you will have to make the C# code pass the allocated pointer back to the DLL so it can be freed correctly, ie using the C `free()` function if the memory is allocated with `malloc()`.

If two modules share memory with each other, but do not agree on a common memory manager (such as one provided by the OS), then the module that allocates the memory must be the same module to free it, as it is the only module that knows how the memory was allocated and thus how to free it.

Comment: I think the `LMEM_FIXED` flag is also important when you allocate on the C++ side, as the C# side does this as well. As you might introduce some weird behavior on the C# side

Comment: The OP's actual problem seems to be `Changing the allocated memory size in C++` which frankly, wouldn't be an issue if proper C++ and containers were used. The rest of the code can be simplified with spans. In fact, I'd bet there's an MSDN article somewhere about STL containers interop with .NET

Comment: First hit: [Marshaling .NET and STL Collections in C++/CLI](https://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2014/08/25/marshaling-net-stl-collections-ccli/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This is my first time managing memory like this. I can't free memory in C++. So how should I resize my C# memory in C++, what do you suggest?

Comment: @Mad_Beggar if the memory was allocated with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` on the C# side, the C++ side can use the Win32 `LocalReAlloc()` function, so the new memory can still be freed with `Marshal.FreeHGlobal()` on the C# side

Comment: @RemyLebeau When I use `*vehicles = (dVehicle*) LocalReAlloc(*vehicles, sizeof(dVehicle) * (new_VehSize), LMEM_MOVEABLE);`, I get same error. If I change `LMEM_MOVEABLE` with ` LMEM_FIXED` I get this error; Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. Can you give advice?

Comment: @Mad_Beggar `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` uses `LMEM_FIXED`. `E_HANDLE` means an invalid memory pointer was given to `LocalFree()`. As for the "protected memory" error, that sounds like an access violation. Please provide a [mcve] showing everything you are actually doing on both sides